# Search in RecyclerView with EditText

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I write this code for search in recyclerview with edit text but, when I run the application and input a text that I need to search about it on the edit text in the first letter the recycler content not changed and when I input the second Letter the RecyclerView become empty.
how can I filter the recycler? what is the wrong in my code ?
xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FamilyActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="294dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
            android:hint="Search ..."
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_person_add_black_24dp"
            android:onClick="add_new_family"
            tools:ignore="OnClick" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

code in main activity:

```
public class FamilyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FamilyAdapter familyAdapter;
    Button add_family;
    EditText search;

    List<Family> familyList;
    String patientID = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_family);
        add_family=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        search =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);

        familyList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            patientID = extras.getString("ID");
        }
        loadFamilyList();
        //adding some items to our list

        //creating recyclerView adapter
        FamilyAdapter adapter = new FamilyAdapter(this, familyList);

        //setting adapter to recyclerView
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        addTextListener();

    }

public void addTextListener(){

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int start, int before, int count) {

                query = query.toString().toLowerCase();

                final List<Family> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < familyList.size(); i++) {

                    final String text = familyList.get(i).toString().toLowerCase();
                    if (text.contains(query)) {

                        filteredList.add(familyList.get(i));
                    }
                }

                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(FamilyActivity.this));
                FamilyAdapter fadapter = new FamilyAdapter(FamilyActivity.this,filteredList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(fadapter);
                fadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // data set changed
            }
        });
    }
```

code in adapter:

```
public class FamilyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FamilyAdapter.FamilyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Family> familyList;
private List<Family> familyListFull;

public FamilyAdapter(Context context, List<Family> familyList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.familyList = familyList;
    familyListFull=new ArrayList<>(familyList);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public FamilyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
    return new FamilyViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FamilyViewHolder familyViewHolder, final int position) {
    Family family = familyList.get(position);
    familyViewHolder.textViewTitle.setText(family.getName());
    familyViewHolder.familyLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on : " + familyList.get(position));
            String name = familyList.get(position).getName();
            String num = familyList.get(position).getNum();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Chatting.class);
            intent.putExtra("num", num);
            intent.putExtra("name", name);
            context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
    familyViewHolder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context );
            builder.setTitle("Delete");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this one ")
                    .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            RemoveFamilyMember(position);
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
            alert.show();


        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this I think this might work, I haven't tested it but I think that making a new adapter everytime that the edittext has something in it is a bad idea. and if you get to the point back to where the query is equal to "" empty string then you should make the fileterd list back into the whole list which I didn't put in there

```
public class FamilyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FamilyAdapter familyAdapter;
    Button add_family;
    EditText search;

    List<Family> familyList;
    List<Family> filteredList;
    String patientID = "";
    FamilyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_family);
        add_family=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        search =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);

        familyList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            patientID = extras.getString("ID");
        }
        loadFamilyList();
        filteredList = new ArrayList<>(familyList);
        //adding some items to our list

        //creating recyclerView adapter
        adapter = new FamilyAdapter(this, filteredList);

        //setting adapter to recyclerView
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        addTextListener();

    }

public void addTextListener(){

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int start, int before, int count) {

                query = query.toString().toLowerCase();

                filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < familyList.size(); i++) {

                    final String text = familyList.get(i).toString().toLowerCase();
                    if (text.contains(query)) {

                        filteredList.add(familyList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                                    recyclerView.removeAllViews();;
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // data set changed
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, the recyclerview no longer disappears ,but it does not work as a filter for items, since the items remain the same.Can you help me solve this problem too?

Answer (score 0):

```
editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            filter(s.toString());

        }
    });
```

```
private void filter(String text) {
    ArrayList<Model> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Model item : mModelList) {
        if (item.getTitle().contains(text)){
            newList.add(item);
        }
    }
    yourAdapter.setFilter(newList);
}
```